# Grails HQL Named Parameters Not Working

Tags: grails, hql, grails-3.0.9

Platform
| Grails Version: 3.0.7
| Groovy Version: 2.4.4
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_51

I seem unable to use named parameters in a Grails HQL query.  The following works (inside a Grails service class).

```
    def query = 'from Event event ' +
                'where event.eventName like ? ' +
                'or event.address.town like ?'
    def results = Event.executeQuery(query, ["%London%", "%London%"], [offset: 5, max: 5])
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
    def query = 'from Event event ' +
                'where event.eventName like :searchEventName ' +
                'or event.address.town like :searchTownName'
    def results = Event.executeQuery(query, [searchEventName, "%London%", searchTownName, "%London%"], [offset: 5, max: 5])
```

The error shown is :

```
Class
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
null
Caused by
No such property: searchEventName for class: com.mchq.event.SearchService
```

Going against what I think is correct, I then declare the properties ...

```
    def searchEventName, searchTownName
    def query = 'from Event event ' +
                'where event.eventName like :searchEventName ' +
                'or event.address.town like :searchTownName'
    def results = Event.executeQuery(query, [searchEventName, "%London%", searchTownName, "%London%"], [offset: 5, max: 5])
```

and the error reported is :

```
Class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message
null
Caused by
No positional parameters in query: from Event event where event.eventName like :searchEventName or event.address.town like :searchTownName
```

As one last test, I try the following having removed the variable declarations and the named param list.

```
    def query = 'from Event event ' +
                'where event.eventName like :searchEventName ' +
                'or event.address.town like :searchTownName'
    def results = Event.executeQuery(query, [offset: 5, max: 5])
```

And quite rightly, the message comes back as :

```
Class
org.hibernate.QueryException
Message
null
Caused by
Not all named parameters have been set: [searchEventName, searchTownName] [from Event event where event.eventName like :searchEventName or event.address.town like :searchTownName]
```

Can anybody tell me the mistake I am making?  Positional parameters seem to be working just find but passing a map of named parameters in causing this strange error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making big typo as in case of named query we pass map not list. See code below:

```
def query = 'from Event event ' +
                'where event.eventName like :searchEventName ' +
                'or event.address.town like :searchTownName'
    def results = Event.executeQuery(query, [searchEventName: "%London%", searchTownName: "%London%"], [offset: 5, max: 5])
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I repeatedly looked at the code and couldn't see a difference between a , and a : arrrrrrgh!

Answer (score 1):

The way you have passed the parameters is wrong. `[searchEventName, "%London%", searchTownName, "%London%"]` is a List in groovy.

You need to specify these as a Map. A Map is defined as `[key1:value1, key2:value2].`

So the correct way to pass parameters will be `[searchEventName: "%London%", searchTownName: "%London%"]`